# Android Licensing Service - LicenseChecker always times out

Tags: android

I'm implementing the licensing service in one of my apps.
I have set the test response to LICENSED.
Anyway it always invokes the dontAllow() function.
Locat sais:

```
08-17 23:44:53.956: INFO/LicenseChecker(479): Binding to licensing service.
08-17 23:44:54.556: INFO/LicenseChecker(479): Calling checkLicense on service for de.goddchen.android.xy
08-17 23:45:04.567: INFO/LicenseChecker(479): Check timed out.
```

So, what am I doing wrong? I'm using a 2.2 API emulator and I configured my publisher google account on it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work on a real phone?  The license mechanism requires the Android Market application to be installed - which isn't present in the emulator.

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction.
"Several versions of the add-on are available in the SDK repository, but only Google APIs Add-On, API 8 (release 2) or higher version of the add-on includes the necessary Android Market services."
I knew that i had to use the API sdk but i didn't know that there was revision2 already, i had installed revision1.